# Rust: Refer to a third .rs file from a second .rs file

Tags: file, rust, module, rust-crates

I have three files:

```
// a.rs

struct MyThing {
}
```

```
// b.rs

mod a;

struct That {
    mything: &a::MyThing;
}
```

```
// main.rs

mod a;
mod b;

fn main() {
    let thing= a::MyThing{};
    let that= b::That{myThing: &thing};
}
```

The compile error I get for a.rs is:

> file not found for module `b`
> help: to create the module `b`, create file "src/a/b.rs" or "src/a/b/mod.rs"

I thought I would need `mod a;` so that I can access the module in `a.rs`, but it looks like since `mod b;` is in `main.rs`, the `mod a;` inside `b.rs` is interpreted relative to `b`...or something.

How do I use one `.rs` file from another?

Answer (score -1):

`mod a;` does not just declare or make reference to the module, a, it **defines** the module, `a`. Putting `mod a;` in `b.rs` creates a separate module from that created in `main.rs`. Instead, let `main.rs` create the modules and make reference to `a` in `b`. In this case, you need to make reference it according to its crate. In which crate is the module `./b.rs`? The root crate, `crate`:

```
// b.rs

use crate::a;

struct That {
    mything: &a::MyThing;
}
```